# Scipy - Inequality constraints incompatible

Tags: python, python-3.x

Any idea what this means? I'm new to Python so What I'm doing in general is probably not correct, but just wanted the constraint to be X[0] >= 0 but it says it's incompatible.

```
def objective (x):
    global sumIp
    global sumIm
    if (NIt[i-1] < s[i-1]):
        NIt[i] = NIt[i-1] - d[i-1] + x[0]
    else:
        NIt[i] = NIt[i-1] - d[i-1]
    It[i] = NIt[i] - d[i] - x[0] + Qt[i-LT]
    if It[i] >= 0:
        sumIp = sumIp+It[i]
        sumIm = sumIm+0
    elif It[i] < 0:
        sumIp = sumIp+0
        sumIm = sumIm-It[i]
    return h*sumIp+b*sumIm


def constraint1 (x):
    return x[0]

(...)

x0 = 1
con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1}
cons = [con1]
sol = minimize(objective, x0, constraints=cons)
```

This is what sol returns (keep in mind it's included in a loop so only printing the last iteration right now)

```
fun: 26249.99991133809
jac: array([3.99297739e+10])
message: 'Inequality constraints incompatible'
nfev: 3
nit: 1
njev: 1
status: 4
success: False
x: array([1.])
```

Comment: I wonder what your constraint1 function does. It takes list `x` and returns the first item in it. Could it be that you are mixing up `x[0]` with `x0`?

Comment: x[0] is ambiguous I guess, x is a single value. It's a quantity so I don't want it to be negative.

Comment: What's the point in defining a function that returns exactly the argument that it receives?

Comment: Not sure. What I had wasn't great. I've now changed my code a lot, I'll create a different question I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late to this, but did you instead need bounds?

```
b = (0, Inf)
sol = minimize(objective, x0, bounds = b)
```